# Creating a loop for time series plot in R

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

I am trying to filter each country in the df_period5 dataset, count the number of objects 'n' for each country, fill the dataset for missing dates using the complete function, change NA to 0 and plot a timeseries for each country. Here's the code I have:

```
for (i in country_count$Country){filter(df_period5,Country=='i')%>%mutate(period5=as.Date(period5))%>%complete(period5=seq.Date(min(period5), max(period5), by="year"))%>%mutate(n= ifelse(is.na(n), 0,   n))%>%
   ggplot( aes(x=period5, y=n)) +
   geom_area(fill="blue", alpha=0.5) +
   geom_line(color="blue") +
  ylab("Number of Objects") +
  theme_ipsum()+labs(title= 'Number of Aquired Objects Over Time in i ')
```

I am not familiar with writing loops function for with a such a long series of actions and would really appreciate any guidance.

Comment: Change ``Country=='i'`` to ``Country==i``. In general you can always debug your code as follows. Set ``i = country_count$Country[1]`` - you take the first element in the loop. Next, run the code within ``{ }`` and set the ``i`` where necessary so that the code would run in your console. If everything works, try the loop again. In addition, consider ``unique(country_count$Country)`` as a standard good practice to avoid duplicated indices when looping

Comment: @runr Thank you for your answer. I changed Country==i. The code runs but is not outputting any plot. Should I add i = country_count$Country[1]  and i = country_count$Country[1]  in the function?

Comment: Inside a for-loop you have to put plots inside the `print(ggplot(........))` function